# How do i uninstall a dual boot 11.10?

Tags: dual-boot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Uninstall ubuntu 11.04/11.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/138032/uninstall-ubuntu-11-04-11-10)

I dual booted 11.10 a while ago and it got messed up to where i can't use it at all. Is there a way to uninstall a dual boot so i can install the newest 12.04 version of Ubuntu? Please help!