# Ubuntu 13.10 clean install not really clean?

Tags: installation, 13.10, gparted

I had Ubuntu 12.04 on my laptop but it went unstable after some automatic updates. The Ethernet connection would not work anymore (it couldn't find any network devices anymore) and the only way to turn the computer off was by removing the battery. I also had many pop-ups with error messages.

I've tried many things now - installing 12.04.0, installing 12.04.3 and 13.10, but it's always the same (errors and the number of error messages vary a bit - for example with one installation the touchpad didn't work either). It doesn't matter if I do the "Erase and reinstall" or "Something else" and choose manually to format Ext4, the problems are still the same. But, when I run Ubuntu from my USB stick, then everything works! So, the clean install is not really clean? How can I get it to really delete everything and get Ubuntu to run from my hard drive as good as it runs from USB stick?

Comment: have you tried using parted magic to erase the entire disk?
https://partedmagic.com/

Comment: Given the same GParted version number, there is no difference between GParted running from the live media and Parted Magic. No inexplicable magic involved there, just a GUI to parted.

Answer (score 0):

With exception of `/home` a clean install is really clean. [As you can see in your installation logs.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/142925/reinstalling-ubuntu-without-formatting-partition-what-folders-are-deleted/143052#143052) Instead of countless attempts to fix issues by just reinstalling the operating system you should instead try to:

- Make screenshots, photos or write down the error messages.
- Put them into your favorite internet search engine, because you might not be the only one getting these error messages. If you get no results for the exact error message, try to remove overly specific information like your username in paths and try again.
- Open a separate question for each problem you cannot solve yourself with the corresponding error message(s) and provide further details regarding the problem.

See also: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)