# How do I obtain log info from the installer?

Tags: ubiquity

I have prepared a PXE-preseed-netinstall configuration for a cluster I am setting up. On all nodes, the install process works perfectly. But I have one node for which the installer *freeze* when *installing the base system*. I suspect a failure on disk (it is a hardware RAID, in fact).

Is there a way to store the logs of the install? This could maybe help to understand what is going on on that node...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The installer logs to `/var/log/installer`

I believe the mini.iso uses the debian-installer: See this page for more info on debugging the installer:

- https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/i386/ch06s01.html.en
- https://wiki.debian.org/DebianInstaller
- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingUbiquity

Comment: thanks actually this part was important: *Error messages and logs are redirected to the fourth console. You can access this console by pressing Left Alt+F4* . Thanks