# Ubuntu 22.04.1 installation fails on a multiboot EFI box

Tags: boot, system-installation, uefi, 22.04

Been trying to install Jammy Jellyfish on my desktop without much luck. It is about 10 years old, but good enough (dual socket, 24 core, 32GB) for me. It has multiple partitions with multiple OSs (14.04 - 18.04 and some CentOSs). This is what I did in the latest attempt:

1. Created a USB stick with the latest iso using Rufus on a windows laptop. Selected GPT/UEFI.
2. Erased / formatted sdb4 (275GB) as a ext4 file system.
3. With the USB plugged in, selected 'UEFI Sandisk ...' as the first boot method is the boot setup and booted with the USB above.
4. Selected 'Install Ubuntu' and excluded 'download updates/3rd party components', picked sdb4 as '/' and sdb for 'bootloader' installation.
5. Installation goes through, though, when I expand the logs I see some questionable messages.
6. When I boot with the new installation, it fail with the boot.log messages I post below. Messages keep repeating on the black screen.
7. After the failure, I booted with a different OS, mounted sdb4 and looked at `/var/log` and `\var\log\installer`.

Few notes:

- I can still boot in older installations / 'Try Ubuntu' mode.
- During the installation I didn't select any other mount points. But in dmesg there is `[   10.349034] EXT4-fs (sdb7): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro`
- Even when 'download updates' is deselected, the installer is downloading packages.
- There is no `syslog`. `installer` directory has one. There are lots of error-like messages. Not sure which ones are significant.

Anything specific I could try? I am going to try to install w/o internet, minimal install, non-efi install etc.

**boot.log** has following:

```
[  OK  ] Started Show Plymouth Boot Screen.
[  OK  ] Started Forward Password Requests to Plymouth Directory Watch.
[  OK  ] Reached target Local Encrypted Volumes.
[  OK  ] Listening on Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status /dev/rfkill Watch.
[  OK  ] Found device WDC_WD6003FZBX-00GXAB0 Swap.
[  OK  ] Found device WDC_WD6003FZB…B0 EFI\x20System\x20Partition.
         Activating swap /dev/disk/…317a-467b-93f1-ee690afbafea...
         Starting File System Check…/dev/disk/by-uuid/EA06-0118...
[  OK  ] Started File System Check Daemon to report status.
[  OK  ] Activated swap /dev/disk/b…4-317a-467b-93f1-ee690afbafea.
[  OK  ] Finished File System Check…n /dev/disk/by-uuid/EA06-0118.
         Mounting /boot/efi...
[  OK  ] Mounted /boot/efi.
[  OK  ] Reached target Local File Systems.
         Starting Load AppArmor profiles...
         Starting Set console font and keymap...
         Starting Tell Plymouth To Write Out Runtime Data...
..
[FAILED] Failed to start Network Time Synchronization.
..
[FAILED] Failed to start Userspace Out-Of-Memory (OOM) Killer.
..
[FAILED] Failed to start Network Name Resolution.
..
[FAILED] Failed to start Network Name Resolution.
..
[FAILED] Failed to start Network Time Synchronization.
..
[FAILED] Failed to start Userspace Out-Of-Memory (OOM) Killer.
..
[FAILED] Failed to start Network Time Synchronization.
..
[FAILED] Failed to start Network Name Resolution.
...
[FAILED] Failed to start Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack.
..
[FAILED] Failed to start D-Bus System Message Bus.
```

cat **dmesg** selected lines. Most of these appear in the 18.04 boot as well.:

```
[    0.000000] kernel: Linux version 5.15.0-56-generic (buildd@lcy02-amd64-004) (gcc (Ubuntu 11.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.3.0, GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.38) #62-Ubuntu SMP Tue Nov 22 19:54:14 UTC 2022 (Ubuntu 5.15.0-56.62-generic 5.15.64)
[    0.000000] kernel: Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-56-generic root=UUID=ecd8ed11-1cc7-4ed0-8bf8-cff42885d054 ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7
[    0.000000] kernel: secureboot: Secure boot disabled
...
[    0.019485] kernel: ACPI: Early table checksum verification disabled
[    0.168593] kernel: Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-56-generic root=UUID=ecd8ed11-1cc7-4ed0-8bf8-cff42885d054 ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7
[    0.168742] kernel: Unknown kernel command line parameters "splash BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-56-generic", will be passed to user space.
...
[    0.614924] kernel: audit: initializing netlink subsys (disabled)
[    0.835012] kernel: pci_bus 0000:00: Unknown NUMA node; performance will be reduced
[    0.856651] kernel: pci_bus 0000:7f: Unknown NUMA node; performance will be reduced
...
[    0.880354] kernel: pci 0000:00:16.0: can't claim BAR 0 [mem 0xfed0e000-0xfed0e00f 64bit]: no compatible bridge window
[    0.880360] kernel: pci 0000:00:16.1: can't claim BAR 0 [mem 0xfed0e010-0xfed0e01f 64bit]: no compatible bridge window
...
[    1.124676] kernel: platform eisa.0: EISA: Cannot allocate resource for mainboard
[    1.124679] kernel: platform eisa.0: Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 1
[    1.124681] kernel: platform eisa.0: Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 2
[    1.124683] kernel: platform eisa.0: Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 3
...
[    2.164168] kernel: isci 0000:05:00.0: Unable to obtain EFI var data for OEM parms
...
[    3.386093] kernel: sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
...
[    7.552716] systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in File System Check on Root Device being skipped.
[    7.661010] kernel: EXT4-fs (sdb4): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro. Quota mode: none.
[    7.786347] kernel: lp: driver loaded but no devices found
...
[    9.278226] kernel: mei_me 0000:00:16.0: Device doesn't have valid ME Interface
[   10.205888] kernel: usb 2-1.4: 3:3: cannot set freq 16000 to ep 0x86
[   10.256111] kernel: usb 2-1.4: Warning! Unlikely big volume range (=3072), cval->res is probably wrong.
[   31.828737] kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1672254400.199:43): apparmor="DENIED" operation="capable" profile="/usr/sbin/cupsd" pid=1231 comm="cupsd" capability=12  capname="net_admin"
-- END OF FILE --
```

**`installer/syslog`** selected messages

```
Dec 28 18:45:56 ubuntu systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Platform Persistent Storage Archival being skipped.
Dec 28 18:45:56 ubuntu kernel: [    0.000000] secureboot: Secure boot disabled
Dec 28 18:45:56 ubuntu kernel: [    0.016748] ACPI: Early table checksum verification disabled
Dec 28 18:45:56 ubuntu systemd[1]: tmp.mount: Directory /tmp to mount over is not empty, mounting anyway.
Dec 28 18:45:56 ubuntu systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Dispatch Password Requests to Console Directory Watch being skipped.
Dec 28 18:45:56 ubuntu systemd-udevd[1627]: sda: Process '/usr/bin/unshare -m /usr/bin/snap auto-import --mount=/dev/sda' failed with exit code 1.
Dec 28 18:45:56 ubuntu systemd-udevd[1611]: sdb: Process '/usr/bin/unshare -m /usr/bin/snap auto-import --mount=/dev/sdb' failed with exit code 1.
Dec 28 18:45:56 ubuntu systemd-udevd[1582]: sdd: Process '/usr/bin/unshare -m /usr/bin/snap auto-import --mount=/dev/sdd' failed with exit code 1.
Dec 28 18:45:56 ubuntu systemd-udevd[1633]: sdb4: Process '/usr/bin/unshare -m /usr/bin/snap auto-import --mount=/dev/sdb4' failed with exit code 1.
Dec 28 18:45:56 ubuntu systemd-udevd[1622]: event3: Failed to call EVIOCSKEYCODE with scan code 0xc022d, and key code 103: Invalid argument
Dec 28 18:45:56 ubuntu systemd-udevd[1622]: event3: Failed to call EVIOCSKEYCODE with scan code 0xc022e, and key code 108: Invalid argument
Dec 28 18:45:56 ubuntu systemd-udevd[1584]: sdc1: Process '/usr/bin/unshare -m /usr/bin/snap auto-import --mount=/dev/sdc1' failed with exit code 1.
Dec 28 18:45:56 ubuntu systemd-udevd[1638]: video4linux: Process '/usr/lib/snapd/snap-device-helper add snap_firefox_firefox /class/video4linux 0:0' failed with exit code 1.
Dec 28 18:45:56 ubuntu kernel: [    0.162874] Unknown kernel command line parameters "maybe-ubiquity splash --- BOOT_IMAGE=/casper/vmlinuz file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed", will be passed to user space.
Dec 28 18:45:56 ubuntu systemd-udevd[1638]: video4linux: Process '/usr/lib/snapd/snap-device-helper add snap_firefox_geckodriver /class/video4linux 0:0' failed with exit code 1.
Dec 28 18:45:56 ubuntu systemd-udevd[1581]: controlC0: Process '/usr/sbin/alsactl -E HOME=/run/alsa -E XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/alsa/runtime restore 0' failed with exit code 99.
Dec 28 18:45:56 ubuntu systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Dispatch Password Requests to Console Directory Watch being skipped.
Dec 28 18:45:56 ubuntu kernel: [    0.562894] audit: initializing netlink subsys (disabled)
Dec 28 18:45:56 ubuntu systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Platform Persistent Storage Archival being skipped.
Dec 28 18:45:56 ubuntu systemd-udevd[1628]: controlC1: Process '/usr/sbin/alsactl -E HOME=/run/alsa -E XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/alsa/runtime restore 1' failed with exit code 99.
Dec 28 18:45:56 ubuntu systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Dispatch Password Requests to Console Directory Watch being skipped.
Dec 28 18:45:56 ubuntu kernel: [    0.773411] pci_bus 0000:00: Unknown NUMA node; performance will be reduced
Dec 28 18:45:56 ubuntu systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Platform Persistent Storage Archival being skipped.
Dec 28 18:45:56 ubuntu kernel: [    0.798129] pci_bus 0000:80: Unknown NUMA node; performance will be reduced
Dec 28 18:45:56 ubuntu kernel: [    0.801925] pci_bus 0000:ff: Unknown NUMA node; performance will be reduced
Dec 28 18:45:56 ubuntu systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Load AppArmor profiles being skipped.
Dec 28 18:45:56 ubuntu systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Set Up Additional Binary Formats being skipped.
Dec 28 18:45:56 ubuntu systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Store a System Token in an EFI Variable being skipped.
Dec 28 18:45:56 ubuntu systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Commit a transient machine-id on disk being skipped.
Dec 28 18:45:56 ubuntu kernel: [    0.816383] pci 0000:00:16.0: can't claim BAR 0 [mem 0xfed0e000-0xfed0e00f 64bit]: no compatible bridge window
Dec 28 18:45:56 ubuntu kernel: [    0.816389] pci 0000:00:16.1: can't claim BAR 0 [mem 0xfed0e010-0xfed0e01f 64bit]: no compatible bridge window
Dec 28 18:45:56 ubuntu kernel: [    1.053035] platform eisa.0: EISA: Cannot allocate resource for mainboard
Dec 28 18:45:56 ubuntu kernel: [    1.053038] platform eisa.0: Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 1
Dec 28 18:45:56 ubuntu systemd[1]: sssd-nss.socket: Bound to unit sssd.service, but unit isn't active.
Dec 28 18:45:56 ubuntu systemd[1]: Dependency failed for SSSD NSS Service responder socket.
Dec 28 18:45:56 ubuntu systemd[1]: sssd-nss.socket: Job sssd-nss.socket/start failed with result 'dependency'.
Dec 28 18:45:56 ubuntu systemd[1]: sssd-autofs.socket: Bound to unit sssd.service, but unit isn't active.
Dec 28 18:45:56 ubuntu avahi-daemon[2227]: No service file found in /etc/avahi/services.
Dec 28 18:45:56 ubuntu casper-md5check[2228]: Checking ./pool/main/l/lto-disabled-list/lto-disabled-list_24_all.deb..../pool/main/l/lto-disabled-list/lto-disabled-list_24_all.deb: OK
Dec 28 18:45:56 ubuntu thermald[2255]: Unsupported cpu model or platform
Dec 28 18:46:02 ubuntu udisksd[2262]: failed to load module mdraid: libbd_mdraid.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Dec 28 18:46:03 ubuntu udisksd[2262]: Failed to load the 'mdraid' libblockdev plugin
Dec 28 18:46:05 ubuntu NetworkManager[2230]: <info>  [1672253165.6081] ifupdown: interfaces file /etc/network/interfaces doesn't exist
Dec 28 18:46:05 ubuntu NetworkManager[2230]: <info>  [1672253165.8886] failed to open /run/network/ifstate
Dec 28 18:46:09 ubuntu networkd-dispatcher[2236]: No valid path found for iw
Dec 28 18:46:09 ubuntu dbus-daemon[2229]: [system] Activation via systemd failed for unit 'dbus-org.freedesktop.network1.service': Unit dbus-org.freedesktop.network1.service not found.
Dec 28 18:46:09 ubuntu networkd-dispatcher[2415]: WARNING: systemd-networkd is not running, output will be incomplete.
Dec 28 18:46:09 ubuntu networkd-dispatcher[2236]: ERROR:Unknown state for interface NetworkctlListState(idx=1, name='lo', type='loopback', operational='n/a', administrative='unmanaged'): n/a
Dec 28 18:46:09 ubuntu networkd-dispatcher[2236]:     raise UnknownState(operational_state)
Dec 28 18:46:09 ubuntu networkd-dispatcher[2236]: UnknownState: n/a
Dec 28 18:46:09 ubuntu networkd-dispatcher[2236]: ERROR:Unknown state for interface NetworkctlListState(idx=2, name='enp6s0f0', type='ether', operational='n/a', administrative='unmanaged'): n/a
Dec 28 18:46:09 ubuntu networkd-dispatcher[2236]:     raise UnknownState(operational_state)
Dec 28 18:46:09 ubuntu networkd-dispatcher[2236]: UnknownState: n/a
Dec 28 18:46:09 ubuntu networkd-dispatcher[2236]: ERROR:Unknown state for interface NetworkctlListState(idx=3, name='enp6s0f1', type='ether', operational='n/a', administrative='unmanaged'): n/a
Dec 28 18:46:09 ubuntu networkd-dispatcher[2236]:     raise UnknownState(operational_state)
Dec 28 18:46:09 ubuntu networkd-dispatcher[2236]: UnknownState: n/a
Dec 28 18:46:12 ubuntu systemd[1]: Started Download data for packages that failed at package install time.
Dec 28 18:46:26 ubuntu kernel: [   76.259856] audit: type=1400 audit(1672253186.207:32): apparmor="DENIED" operation="mkdir" profile="snap-update-ns.firefox" name="/usr/share/libreoffice/help/" pid=2568 comm="6" requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=0 ouid=0
Dec 28 18:46:26 ubuntu kernel: [   76.262051] audit: type=1400 audit(1672253186.207:33): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap-update-ns.firefox" name="/var/lib/" pid=2568 comm="6" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0
Dec 28 18:47:28 ubuntu pulseaudio[2599]: GetManagedObjects() failed: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.
Dec 28 18:47:35 ubuntu ubiquity[2649]: Trying to update apt indexes to run ubuntu-drivers against fresh data.
Dec 28 18:47:43 ubuntu kernel: [  153.468842] audit: type=1400 audit(1672253263.416:34): apparmor="DENIED" operation="capable" profile="/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine" pid=4524 comm="snap-confine" capability=12  capname="net_admin"
Dec 28 18:47:43 ubuntu kernel: [  153.468862] audit: type=1400 audit(1672253263.416:35): apparmor="DENIED" operation="capable" profile="/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine" pid=4524 comm="snap-confine" capability=38  capname="perfmon"
Dec 28 18:47:43 ubuntu kernel: [  153.473100] audit: type=1400 audit(1672253263.420:36): apparmor="DENIED" operation="capable" profile="/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine" pid=4524 comm="snap-confine" capability=4  capname="fsetid"
Dec 28 18:47:47 ubuntu snapd-desktop-i[4524]: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
Dec 28 18:47:47 ubuntu snapd-desktop-i[4524]: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
Dec 28 18:47:49 ubuntu systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Auto import assertions from block devices being skipped.
Dec 28 18:47:50 ubuntu ubiquity[2649]: ubuntu-drivers list-oem finished with no available packages. Maybe we need to apt update? Doing that and trying again.
Dec 28 18:47:50 ubuntu ubiquity[2649]: We've already apt updated and run, not doing so again.
Dec 28 18:47:50 ubuntu ubiquity[2649]: No, we didn't find any OEM packages again.
Dec 28 18:50:30 ubuntu systemd[1]: Starting Download data for packages that failed at package install time...
Dec 28 18:50:30 ubuntu systemd[1]: Finished Download data for packages that failed at package install time.
Dec 28 18:51:10 ubuntu kernel: [  360.573551] EXT4-fs (sdb4): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: errors=remount-ro. Quota mode: none.
Dec 28 18:56:07 ubuntu ubiquity: py_compile.py: error: the following arguments are required: filenames
Dec 28 18:56:07 ubuntu ubiquity: py_compile.py: error: the following arguments are required: filenames
Dec 28 18:56:07 ubuntu ubiquity: chroot: failed to run command ‘pyversions’
Dec 28 18:56:07 ubuntu ubiquity: : No such file or directory
Dec 28 18:56:29 ubuntu ubiquity: umount: /target/cdrom: no mount point specified.
Dec 28 18:56:30 ubuntu ubiquity: /usr/lib/ubiquity/apt-setup/generators/01setup: 9: cannot open /target/etc/apt/sources.list: No such file
Dec 28 18:56:30 ubuntu apt-setup: dpkg-divert: warning: diverting file '/sbin/start-stop-daemon' from an Essential package with rename is dangerous, use --no-rename
Dec 28 18:56:30 ubuntu /usr/bin/in-target: warning: /target/etc/mtab won't be updated since it is a symlink.
Dec 28 18:56:34 ubuntu in-target: W: Download is performed unsandboxed as root as file '/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/Ubuntu%2022.04.1%20LTS%20%5fJammy%20Jellyfish%5f%20-%20Release%20amd64%20(20220809.1)_dists_jammy_InRelease' couldn't be accessed by user '_apt'. - pkgAcquire::Run (13: Permission denied)
Dec 28 18:57:00 ubuntu apt-setup: dpkg-divert: warning: diverting file '/sbin/start-stop-daemon' from an Essential package with rename is dangerous, use --no-rename
Dec 28 18:57:00 ubuntu /usr/bin/in-target: warning: /target/etc/mtab won't be updated since it is a symlink.
Dec 28 18:57:12 ubuntu in-target: W: Download is performed unsandboxed as root as file '/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_jammy-security_InRelease' couldn't be accessed by user '_apt'. - pkgAcquire::Run (13: Permission denied)
Dec 28 18:57:33 ubuntu plugininstall.py: Try to fix these broken packages: libreoffice-help-de, libreoffice-help-en-gb, libreoffice-help-es, libreoffice-help-fr, libreoffice-help-it, libreoffice-help-pt, libreoffice-help-pt-br, libreoffice-help-ru, libreoffice-help-zh-cn, libreoffice-help-zh-tw, libreoffice-math, python3-uno, thunderbird-gnome-support, thunderbird-locale-de, thunderbird-locale-es, thunderbird-locale-fr, thunderbird-locale-it, thunderbird-locale-pt, thunderbird-locale-ru, thunderbird-locale-zh-hans, thunderbird-locale-zh-hant.
Dec 28 18:58:21 ubuntu check-missing-firmware: /dev/.udev/firmware-missing does not exist, skipping
Dec 28 18:58:21 ubuntu check-missing-firmware: /run/udev/firmware-missing does not exist, skipping
Dec 28 18:58:21 ubuntu check-missing-firmware: no missing firmware in loaded kernel modules
Dec 28 18:58:56 ubuntu ubiquity:   Cannot process volume group sdb
Dec 28 18:59:37 ubuntu ubiquity: dpkg-divert: warning: diverting file '/sbin/start-stop-daemon' from an Essential package with rename is dangerous, use --no-rename
Dec 28 18:59:37 ubuntu /usr/bin/in-target: warning: /target/etc/mtab won't be updated since it is a symlink.
Dec 28 19:02:41 ubuntu ubiquity: Purging configuration files for witalian (1.10) ...#015
Dec 28 19:02:42 ubuntu ubiquity: Purging configuration files for wspanish (1.0.29) ...#015
Dec 28 19:02:45 ubuntu ubiquity: Purging configuration files for keyutils (1.6.1-2ubuntu3) ...#015
Dec 28 19:02:46 ubuntu ubiquity: Purging configuration files for dmeventd (2:1.02.175-2.1ubuntu4) ...#015
Dec 28 19:02:46 ubuntu ubiquity: Purging configuration files for dbus-x11 (1.12.20-2ubuntu4) ...#015
Dec 28 19:02:47 ubuntu ubiquity: Purging configuration files for mozc-data (2.26.4220.100+dfsg-5.2) ...#015
Dec 28 19:03:23 ubuntu ubiquity: Removing libnfsidmap1:amd64 (1:2.6.1-1ubuntu1) ...#015
Dec 28 19:03:24 ubuntu ubiquity: Removing libnss-sss:amd64 (2.6.3-1ubuntu3.1) ...#015
Dec 28 19:03:24 ubuntu ubiquity: Removing libpath-utils1:amd64 (0.6.2-1) ...#015
Dec 28 19:03:25 ubuntu ubiquity: Removing libref-array1:amd64 (0.6.2-1) ...#015
Dec 28 19:03:25 ubuntu ubiquity: Removing libsss-certmap0 (2.6.3-1ubuntu3.1) ...#015
Dec 28 19:03:25 ubuntu ubiquity: Removing libsss-idmap0 (2.6.3-1ubuntu3.1) ...#015
Dec 28 19:03:26 ubuntu ubiquity: Removing libsss-nss-idmap0 (2.6.3-1ubuntu3.1) ...#015
Dec 28 19:03:26 ubuntu ubiquity: Removing python3-sss (2.6.3-1ubuntu3.1) ...#015
Dec 28 19:03:28 ubuntu ubiquity: Purging configuration files for sssd-common (2.6.3-1ubuntu3.1) ...#015
Dec 28 19:03:28 ubuntu ubiquity: Purging configuration files for sssd-ad-common (2.6.3-1ubuntu3.1) ...#015
Dec 28 19:03:29 ubuntu ubiquity: Purging configuration files for libnss-sss:amd64 (2.6.3-1ubuntu3.1) ...#015
Dec 28 19:03:31 ubuntu plugininstall.py: Try to fix these broken packages: libnss-systemd, libpam-systemd, libreoffice-math, python3-uno, systemd-oomd, systemd-sysv, systemd-timesyncd, thunderbird-gnome-support.
Dec 28 19:04:16 ubuntu ubiquity: grub-install: warning: EFI variables cannot be set on this system.#015
Dec 28 19:04:16 ubuntu ubiquity: grub-install: warning: You will have to complete the GRUB setup manually.#015
Dec 28 19:04:16 ubuntu ubiquity: Installation finished. No error reported.#015
```

Comment: My 10 year old computer does not have UEFI, try BIOS, (Legacy), install or try using Etcher to create the Live USB.

Comment: A 10 year old UEFI, is early UEFI. Make sure you have latest firmware. But C.S.Cameron's suggest may be easier. If installing to sdb, you were bitten by this ubiquity bug. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1396379 If you have ESP on sdb, you can use Boot-Repair to reinstall grub using Advanced mode. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair & 
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/  I like to turn off os-prober so old installs are not in grub menu. I backup first run of grub.cfg and only copy boot stanza I want into 40_custom.

Comment: On a hunch I ran `shred -n 1 -v /dev/sdb4` after step '2' and it all worked!! I had the feeling that even after selecting 'erase' option when reformatting, somehow the installer manage to pick some things from a previous installation on the partition because I was getting the message mentioned [here]{https://askubuntu.com/questions/142925/reinstalling-ubuntu-without-formatting-partition-what-folders-are-deleted}.

Comment: @C.S.Cameron , thanks for the hint on Etcher. I don't have to go looking for window machines next time.

Comment: @oldfred, thanks. You are right on multiple fronts. I started with EFI at the time only because it allowed GPT and EFI add one more thing to the mix of things that I am not too familiar with. And yes, installer always update the EFI partition on `sda`. I had a EFI partition on sdb as well, but found that it is not used. Deleted it earlier today after reading some of the errors I was getting were due to not having enough space at the start of sdb for bootloader.

Comment: In BIOS boot mode on gpt drive,  you need a tiny 1 or 2 MB unformatted partition. If using gparted add bios_grub flag. If gdisk it is code ef02. Actual code in partition is some very long type GUID.