# Upgrade Ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04 using a bootable USB stick

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, live-usb, live-cd, 16.04

I use Ubuntu 14.04 and I want to upgrade my version of Ubuntu to the latest 16.04 LTS release. One way to do that is using the `update-manager`. Is there any other way to do it ? Like using a  bootable USB stick with 16.04 on it.

Comment: This https://askubuntu.com/questions/396727/upgrade-ubuntu-option-not-availiable-when-installing-from-usb-stick might help

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you @Bruni

Answer (score 1):

Go to your Unity Dash, locate "Startup creator" and create a bootable installation USB disk using it. You will of course first download the *.iso image. Make sure that your USB is recognized when you plug it in, so that the creator knows which drive to use.

Then boot your computer using the USB.

Answer (score 0):

**Upgrade your system**

First you have to check if there is a new version of Ubuntu

```
sudo do-release-upgrade -d
```

Wait for the system to finish installing , it takes time patience is needed :-) ..
When it finishes reboot Ubuntu

**Verify all packages are up to date**

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt full-upgrade
```

**Clear the cache**

You don't want to keep that 1 or 2 Go of dependencies slowing down your system of course

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

**Verify your version**

```
lsb_release -a
```

You should get Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Xenial Xerius as output

Comment: so, where does the USB fit in?

Comment: "USB stick"?? Anything about that?

Comment: The USB stick was just an example of "any other way". Please read the question before you downvote this answer.

Comment: take a look in this site:https://askubuntu.com/questions/138032/how-to-replace-an-old-version-of-ubuntu-with-a-newer-one-from-usb-dvd